# How to convert NSArray to NSData?

Tags: iphone

Can anyone tell me how to convert an `NSArray` to an `NSData`? I have an `NSArray`. I need to send it to an `NSInputStream`. In order to do that I need to convert the `NSArray` to an `NSData`.

Please help me, I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Use NSKeyedArchiver (which is the last sentence of the post Garrett links):

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

Note that all the objects in `array` must conform to the `NSCoding` protocol. If these are custom objects, then that means you need to read up on [Encoding and Decoding Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html).

Note that this will create a fairly hard-to-read property list format, but can handle a very wide range of objects. If you have a very simple array (strings for instance), you may want to use NSPropertyListSerialization, which creates a bit simpler property list:

```
NSString *error;
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:array format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
```

There's also an XML format constant you can pass if you'd rather it be readable on the wire.

Answer (score 94):

On a somewhat related note, here's how you would convert the NSData back to an NSArray:

```
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]
```

Comment: Make sure that it's NSKeyedUnarchiver and not NSKeyedArchiver.  Can be an easy mistake to make when using auto complete.

Comment: This answer, coupled with the chosen answer from above should be sufficient to archive/unarchive any compatible object to/from NSData

Answer (score 3):

I used this code.

```
 NSError *error;
 NSMutableData *jsonData = [[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:yourDemoArray
                                                                   options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                                     error:&error] copy];
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift :

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: jsonArray)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this-

```
NSArray *array= [NSArray array];
NSData *dataArray = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9+ use this please:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:array format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil];
```

The older version of this was deprecated in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: array, requiringSecureCoding: true)
```