# how convert NSDictionary element to NSData (dataUsingEncoding cause crash)

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary, nsdata, unrecognized-selector

i try to convert NSDictionary element to a NSData element:

```
...    
while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) 
    {
        NSString *temp = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"results"]) 
        {
            //Crash HERE! -------------------------->>>>
            NSData *myData2 = [temp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];

            NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:myData2 error:&error];
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
            //print dictionary
            NSEnumerator *enumerator2 = [dictionary2 keyEnumerator];
            id key2;
            while (key2 = [enumerator2 nextObject]) 
            {
                NSLog(@"Chiave: %@ | valore: %@",key2,[dictionary objectForKey:key2] );
            }

        }
    }
...
```

but in this way crash with:

```
    -[__NSArrayI dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b1c590
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b1c590'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x025fe919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0274c5de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0260042b -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02570116 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0256fcd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   taxi rider                          0x00002722 -[taxi_riderViewController viewDidLoad] + 1508
    6   UIKit                               0x00375c26 -[UIViewController view] + 179
    7   taxi rider                          0x00001f61 -[taxi_riderAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 74
    8   UIKit                               0x002ce543 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    9   UIKit                               0x002d09a1 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 346
    10  UIKit                               0x002da452 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1958
    11  UIKit                               0x002d3074 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    12  UIKit                               0x002d7ac4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7495
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x02c78afa PurpleEventCallback + 1578
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x025dfdc4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x02540737 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0253d9c3 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0253d280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0253d1a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    19  UIKit                               0x002d0226 -[UIApplication _run] + 625
    20  UIKit                               0x002dbb58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  taxi rider                          0x00001ef4 main + 102
    22  taxi rider                          0x00001e85 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`-dataUsingEncoding:` is an NSString method.

According to the error message, the object you're sending it to is not an NSString, it's an `NSArray`.

If you are trying to convert an `NSArray` to `NSData`, see [How to convert NSArray to NSData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286212/how-to-convert-nsarray-to-nsdata)

Or, since it appears you're expecting to be able to read the `NSData` object with `[CJSONDeserializer deserializer]`, you should probably create it with whatever the inverse of that is (is there a `CJSONSerializer` class in that package?).

Comment: I use [CJSONDeserializer deserializer] to convert a json file to a dictionary, unfortunately the deserializer parsing only a small part of the json file, and create a dictionary containing a string and an array, i suppose must re-parsing the array