# NSArray writeToFile not working first time (but works next time)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, plist, writetofile

I am writing a huge NSArray of NSDictionaries. The file size when successfully written to a plist is about 549KB. The thing is, when I start my app, the first time I try to write it, it always returns NO (i.e. it didn't write), but then the next time it write just fine...Is there any way I can find out exactly what error occurred? Thanks.

Comment: [data writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

Comment: :) That much I guessed. Where are you writing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be your array of dictionaries is empty? Try to debug your app.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is, it always happen the first time ONLY.

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSData - writeToFile:options:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile%3aoptions%3aerror%3a) instead and see what does the returned error (NSError) say.

Comment: @user635064 See [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286212/how-to-convert-nsarray-to-nsdata) for converting an `NSArray` to `NSData`.