# Sending hexadecimal data to devices (Converting NSString to hexadecimal data)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, hex, nsdata

I'm trying to send hexadecimal data via WiFi.

The code is something like this:

```
NSString *abc = @"0x1b 0x50";
NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithData:[abc dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]autorelease];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]]];
```

Instead of sending the hexadecimal data, it's sending it in text format. 
I tried with `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, but it's the same. I'm using it with the `NSStream` class.

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting what you expect with `NSString *abc = @"0x1b 0x50"`. It's almost the same as having `NSString *abc = @"cat dog 123 0x0x0x"`; just a bunch of words separated by spaces. So when you create your `NSData` object, you're just initializing it with a string of characters, not a series of actual numbers.

If you can get your numbers into an `NSArray`, this question/answer should help you: [How to convert NSArray to NSData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286212/how-to-convert-nsarray-to-nsdata)

Answer (score 0):

The data that you probably want to send is simply 0x1b50, which is the decimal number 6992 (assuming big-endian), and fits into two bytes. This is not the same as a string (which could contain anything) even if it happens to contain some human-readable representation of those numbers.

I'm assuming you want to send this as binary data, and if so one way would be to simply send a buffer formed by a single `UInt16` instead of a string. I'm not very familiar with the relevant APIs, but look to see if you can populate the NSData with an integer, perhaps something like:

```
UInt16 i = 0x1b50; // Or = 6992
[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: &i length: sizeof(i)]

[outputStream write: [data bytes] maxLength: [data length]]];
```

Again, I'm not fluent with Objective C, but this should be the general approach to sending the number 0x1b50 as binary data.

Comment: hey guys. thanks a lot. its working now. 
but i still need to learn how to parse an array of binary data.