# Convert NSArray of bytes to NSData

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, arrays

I'm trying to download a file in Objective-C from a REST service but having some issues. Right now, the service returns a byte[] in JSON. I was able to get the array by using the json-framework.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.10.215:8888/Service/RO/GetAllTheBytes/test.txt"];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [str JSONValue];
NSArray *fileContents = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"fileContents"];
```

Now I want to use this array of bytes to create a file, but I'm having trouble creating the file. Should I convert the `NSArray` to `NSData`, and how?

Comment: Why do you save fileContents in `NSArray`? I suppose `NSString` will be better choose. And `NSString` can be converted to byte[] when you need this

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286212/how-to-convert-nsarray-to-nsdata

Comment: JSON doesn't have a byte type. Are you getting back maybe an array of numbers, a string of hexadecimal digits, a base64 encoded string, or something else?

Comment: I'm seeing an array of numbers.

Comment: @Nekto - how do you convert NSString to byte[]?

Answer (score 1):

Change your service to return a Base64 string. There are a bunch of Objective-C Base64 decoders out there, some of which are half-decent.

A NSArray of NSNumbers is really *really* **really** stupid, with a minimum space overhead of about 300% (although not quite as bad as [JRA-11693](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/)).