# Saving and loading presets in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, file-management, preset

I have a synth iOS app in development. I have a lot of interactive objects there, like knobs, sliders, buttons and so on. I want to let user save and load his presets and be able to share them with iTunes. So I think I must write all parameters to variables and save arrays of variables to files, right? There are about 100 float and int variables in one preset.

It's my first project, sorry if it is common question. I've made some research and discovered that there are a lot of options to handle presets data. But I stuck and it would be great if you can help me to choose direction.

Answer (score 1):

If it's all about preset, NSUserDefaults is the way to go. But having 100 values might slow the loading/saving a little bit.

To serialize a NSArray or a plist: [How to convert NSArray to NSData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286212/how-to-convert-nsarray-to-nsdata)