# NSMutableData appendData with NSArray data

Tags: ios, nsmutabledata

To append a simple string key-value pair, we do this in object C

```
   NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\";\r\n\r\n%@", _name, _value] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

However, how do we append  NSArray of data.  Let's say Email Array contains={tom@yahoo.com, dve@yahoo.com, john@yahoo.com}

How do we append Email array to the NSMutableData body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can turn your array into NSString as you did with single string:

```
NSArray array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
...
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", array] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

but I recommend to use NSKeyedArchiver, see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286212/how-to-convert-nsarray-to-nsdata)