# Saving NSArray of NSDictionary's to File

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, ios5

I'm trying to save a huge NSArray to a file and then retrieve it...

```
NSURL *documentsDirectory = 
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
                            inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *fileURL = [documentsDirectory 
                  URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"scorecards.dgs"];


NSMutableArray *savedArrayOfScorecards = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
[savedArrayOfScorecards addObject:currentScoreCard];

[savedArrayOfScorecards writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];

NSMutableArray *mynewArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];

NSLog(@"%@, %@",[[mynewArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"info"], course);
```

The NSLog comes back with...

```
(null), BridgeMill
```

Which BridgeMill should be returned on both sides of the comma. But array won't save...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if it's being saved correctly:

```
if([savedArrayOfScorecards writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES])
{
    NSLog(@"Was saved");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Houston we have a problem...");
}
```

On the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> - (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)aURL atomically:(BOOL)atomically

You can also use this to check what is going on:

> - (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)aURL options:(NSDataWritingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr

Comment: Ahaha. :) Ok what you can try: 1) check if the path is **in theory** correct. 2) Use the second method and then inspect the `NSError`

Answer (score 0):

what class is `course`?

[`writeToURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BCIGIJII) only supports types that can be converted into plist format. Those types are NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

If you have other types in your NSArray you have to [archive the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286212/how-to-convert-nsarray-to-nsdata).